# File with .cpp,v extension

Tags: c++, version-control, cvs

I 've a c++ code. but its with .cpp,v extension. I want to debug and compile the code. Can anyone please throw some light on that topic. I want to know what v indicates? & how to debug the code?

Answer (score 6):

It's a file from CVS or some related version control system. The files ending with ",v" are not the actual source files, rather these are housekeeping files used by CVS.

You will need to go back to the CVS repository and get the .cpp and .h source file(s).

Comment: what does that CVS mean?? i know nothing about it? could you please give me some idea..

Comment: Concurrent Versioning System, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_Versions_System.

Comment: It could also be from RCS, an even older version control system.

Comment: thanks richb. sorry for troubling you. Where will the repository reside? in CVSROOT directory?.

Comment: in that directory too all are with ,v extension. how to compile those files??

Comment: shayam, you don't compile files ending with ,v. They are not C++ files. Where did you get the files from? Are there also .cpp and .h or perhaps .C files in there as well?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. In CVSROOT directory there are only files with ,v extension. in other directories there are .cpp & .h & .c files..

Comment: ok.. thanks.. which tool s to be used for this? wincvs is the one i am using.